# Is it possible to do margin without using Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget, margin

Is there any low-cost way to do margin without using containers in Flutter?
I don't like to use the container widget just to do margin.

Comment: use Padding widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flutter we generally talk about adding Padding around a widget rather than margin. The Container widget does have a margin parameter, but even this just wraps it child (and any decoration that the child has) with a Padding widget internally.

[image]

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Text(
      "text",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
    ),
),
```

Let's say we have a text widget. We follow a path like this without using containers. I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, using a padding widget is the same as using container with margin. Thank you very much.